# Shiny - Plotly graph not displaying all variables

Tags: r, graph, shiny, pie-chart, shinydashboard

Been working on generating an interactive dashboard using shiny and want to make a pie chart.

I generated a plotly pie chart using the following dataframe

```
   SumRes Total
   (chr)   (int)
 1 1-2 Days   179
 2 3-4 Days   131
 3       5+    68
```

using the code below

```
  plot_ly( Resp_Time, labels = SumRes, values = Total, type = "pie")
```

It produced exactly what I wanted, however when I insert this code into my shiny dashboard I lose the first variable so my plot ends up looking like this:

[image]

Is this a known bug?

Does the ring/donut plot work better than the pie in shiny?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `plot_ly( Resp_Time, labels = ~SumRes, values = ~Total, type = "pie")`. You need to add the `~` character to indicate a formula that involves column names, even if that "formula" is just the column itself.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. In the end, I ended up re-generating the dataframe and found that it was related to incompatibility with the tibble dataframe.